# Few keywords in the heading section, is it bad or good?

Tags: seo, keywords, ranking

My article heading is "how to SEO learn SEO 101 beginner SEO guide" is this. Here is the keyword which is used more than once.

For "how to SEO" and "SEO 101" and "beginner SEO guide", my main target is "how to SEO" and thus I use that in the beginning part of the heading and the other two keywords are used as secondary in the last part. In the content I tried to use keyword "how to SEO" and not to use a lot the other two keywords.

**Questions:**

1. Is it good or bad? And Why?
2. Same keywords reduce targeted keyword value? Describe briefly.

Comment: Write titles that make sense. Your proposed heading reads like spam. Read Google's seo guide http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.co.uk/en/uk/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf

Comment: @user29671 Can you explain more. Why you think this is spamming. I am keeping/writing 3 keywords in my article. Then why it is spamming? Then only "how to seo" should be used as my article heading?

Answer (score 2):

We get these questions a lot!

It is not about keywords and the manipulation of keywords. It has never been the case since the beginning of Google and never will be. So stop. Please. This common SEO advice is utterly ridiculous and made out of complete ignorance of how search engines actually work.

*Here is what you need to know.*

Search engines are semantic engines and have been for a very long time. It is not about keyword matching and has not been since Google came on the scene in 1997/8.

What you want to do is stop thinking in terms of keywords and where and how to place them. You are doing yourself more harm thinking this way. Why? Because fully formed naturally written sentences outperform anything.

Prior to Google search engines performed some predictive analysis along with metrics associated with term matches and term placement in relation to each other and the beginning of the HTML document. In some form, semantics begins here, however, semantics is not term matching at all, but linguistics analysis and algorithmic scoring in matrices. It is this scoring that allows search engines to match search intent. The search engine is not matching keywords, it is matching topic relevancy based upon language and the written word. While this is not technically difficult to understand, it is far more detailed in scope than a simple keyword match and predictive analysis. Semantics and how it is applied gets complex really really fast.

Semantics is not new. It existed as a fully formed analysis engine back in the early to mid-1970s. There have been some new semantic analysis algorithms since then, however, most are predicated on preexisting analysis. Very little is actually new except how it is applied and how inventive the web allows semantic analysis to be. It is really remarkable the depth of how semantics is applied these days. We are very far away from the days of keyword matches.

*To answer your question.*

Write fully formed sentences everywhere possible. Not staccato headlines. Not keyword loaded stuff. It is not necessary. Search engines understand what you are writing better than you can ever imagine. Your h1 tag should apply to the topic of the whole page while any other header tag should apply to the topic of the content immediately following it. What is important are subject, predicate, and object just like you studied in your English classes. If you write fully formed sentences, this is a natural thing you already do. You do not even have to think about it.

Remember to create content for humans and not machines. Part of semantic analysis is determining when what is written is for machines. Some level of analysis can determine if a page is designed for search engines and your content may gain some negative scores as a result. Semantics prefers sentences. One reason for this is that smaller terms can really help understand the topic. For example, I recently described how so-called stop words (and there is no such thing anymore) help search engines understand content. Using the word *a* means singular. While this seems trivial, it becomes a powerful semantic clue at times where a term is used that does not have a plural version.

Creating content for readers helps with so-called long-tail search. Long-tail is a bit of a misnomer. It never really existed except in the keyword chase world. Those who wrote naturally, never had to think in these terms. It was simply a natural by-product. However, those who chased keywords, constantly struggle against the current. It is important to use the right terms of course. For that, you should be aware of the terms used for any topic. In this, search engines can determine expertise and will use expertise levels to make search query matches.

So write naturally written sentences as much as you can and be sure to know your topic and you will be fine. You will not have to think too much. Let the search engines do the thinking for you. After all, are you smarter than almost two decades of engineering by countless linguistics experts at Google?  Short answer? No. None of us are. So do not try and out think them. It does not pay.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, it is bad, because User including my self don't like that type of heading, and Google always improving their system to what user like to see in top search result. And Google already improve their system for that kind of things, so grow up, and stop playing around keywords.
2. Be natural, One keyword is also enough, if many of people links to you, with Good anchor text

Side effect: Well, if you're doing this kind of stuff, then probably less people links to you, so you will get low pagerank + anchor text.

Answer (score 0):

Meta keywords shouldn't bother you as much as the usefulness of the content you've created. It should answer some questions, be a really small part of the Internet that brings some value to whole www community. I know it sounds a bit pompously but that's how Google sees it.
Why this kind of title is spammy? It's just not user friendly - people don't write and talk like that;)

Answer (score -2):

Multiple keywords are accepted in meta keywords and should not create any issue for SEO point of view.

Also not only keywords but contents do matter SEO point of view.  You should have unique content with atleast 250-300 words and try to put keyword once or twice.

Also share it on social media to make it reach to target audience.